# Pigments or Pigmentation Tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I was going through some of the questions after answering [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10041/why-are-the-colours-our-eyes-can-be-limited), and I was noticing a lot of questions deal with pigments and pigmentation.  Searching for color will bring up plenty, but some other recent ones include:

[Why ducklings are yellow?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10008/why-ducklings-are-yellow)

[Is there any natural blue rose?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10026/is-there-any-natural-blue-rose)

Should the tag be pigments or pigmentation?  Do people think this would be a good tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've edited the questions you linked and added a [pigmentation](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pigmentation) tag to them. I chose that over "pigments" as the process of pigmentation is biological, while the word pigments seems to suggest the chemistry of pigment molecules. If you want to do a larger search and retag other questions, feel free.

BTW, since you have greater than 150 reputation, you can [create tags](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) yourself. However, I applaud you for asking here first.

Comment: I knew I could make them myself, but I thought it was worth asking first, especially since we're still a beta.